# Menu in the Magento 2 admin panel not working

Tags: javascript, magento2.2.2

I just installed a fresh copy of Magento 2.2.2 and the menu (the one on the left side) is not working in the admin panel. Nothing happens when you click the icon.

I checked the Chrome console and these errors are showing:
[image]

I am running CentOS 7, Centminmod with PHP 7.1.13. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It is due to network issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try disable static file versionning.

Go in **Store > Config > Advanced > Developer > Static Files Settings > Sign Static Files** and set option to **"No"**.

If you can't navigate in admin, then go to **core_config_data table** in mysql database.

Search for path **'dev/static/sign'** and **set value to 0**.

Clean cache :

```
rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/di/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/
```

Then reload your admin page.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try below listed commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Remove directory `/var/page_cache` `/var/cache` `/var/generation` `/var/view_preprocessed` and `/generated` from root dir. Give it a try and let me know if you still find an issue.

Comment: Are you sure about deleting the var and generated directories? They seem to have important files.

Comment: Don't worry about it magento will create it automatically.

Comment: Deleting /var entirely is not recommended. It holds .htaccess file which should not be deleted. You can find more information about deleting generated files manually in the docs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html

Comment: If you delete whole /var it will create .htaccess as well. But still its not right way I agree. Updated answer.